# How do I fix this Access code

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have multiple people connecting to my Access database and if two people happen to be searching at the same time I get an error. So I did this to fix it and it cut down on the error a lot but I still get it sometimes. Is there a better way? I am pretty sure I shouldn't be using try catch like this .

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\Documents\2015\Db12.accdb";
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\Documents\2015\Db12.accdb";
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            m.Result = (IntPtr)(HT_CAPTION);
    }

    private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    private const int HT_CLIENT = 0x1;
    private const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    private void lRead(string query, ListBox lbox)
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lbox.Items.Add(reader["UAS"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show("error LREAD" + ex); }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            { reader.Dispose(); }
        }
    }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            lRead($"select * from Table1 where UAS Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
            lRead($"select * from Table1 where Customer Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
            lRead($"select * from Table1 where Description Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
            lRead($"select * from Table1 where Detail Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
            //select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like '* PARMA *' dont use * use % 
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                lRead($"select * from Table1 where UAS Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
                lRead($"select * from Table1 where Customer Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
                lRead($"select * from Table1 where Description Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
                lRead($"select * from Table1 where Detail Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
                //select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like '* PARMA *' dont use * use % 
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    listBox1.Items.Clear();
                    lRead($"select * from Table1 where UAS Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
                    lRead($"select * from Table1 where Customer Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
                    lRead($"select * from Table1 where Description Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
                    lRead($"select * from Table1 where Detail Like '%{textBox1.Text}%'", listBox1);
                    //select * from SomeTable Where SomeColumn Like '* PARMA *' dont use * use % 
                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Error too many People Searching ");
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: You have to tell us the error, and which line is causing it.

Comment: it isnt an error i dont need debuging it is just when too many people access it it erors out i need to handle the connections better than a through my try catch

Comment: "it isn't an error" "it errors out". Surely something happens when the issue arises and you can share that.

Comment: 1) change from string injection to parameters, 2) catch _specific exceptions_ rather than catching any exception and assuming that the problem is "too many users connected" 3) dispose of your connections and commands by surrounding them with `using` blocks. 4) Once all those are done, post the _exact_ exception, including message and location, to isolate the problem.

Comment: Also, note that this is ripe for SQL Injection issues.

Comment: Read up on [the `lock` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Comment: Having a single connection object re-used in multiple scopes is a *famously* bad idea.  Connection objects should be created, used, and disposed in as tight a scope as possible.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath not really true at all. Access can handle many simultaneous connections. If you have more than 20-30 then that is starting to get out of what Access can do. But two people, that should be just fine.

Comment: `"i get an error"` - Also, you forgot the part where you actually *describe the error*.  `"i am pretty sure i shouldn't be using try catch like this"` - No, you shouldn't.  Because your `catch` blocks are *ignoring the actual exception*.  Ignoring an error is a terrible way of solving it.

Comment: @Brad You are right, I was confused with the connection limits of Access

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I assume that the exceptions are due to other users on other machines accessing the database, not other threads in his application.

Answer (score 2):

These lines do nothing useful. You allocate a new OleDbConnection() then let it go out of scope. Connections are a limited resource, don't get one you are not going to use.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\Documents\2015\Db12.accdb";
```

The lines

```
private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=S:\Documents\2015\Db12.accdb";
```

should be moved into the methods that actually access the database. Because connections are limited resources, they implement [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). Anything that implements IDisposable should make use of the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure the associated resources are released as soon as possible. You may be limiting your concurrency because you are not doing that here. Instead, you hold on to your connection for the lifetime of the form, plus however long it takes for the garbage collector to clean up the form.

In `textBox1_TextChanged`, you repeat the same code several times. That is error prone (what if you change the code in one place but forget to make the change in other places). If you need this kind of retry logic, use a loop. Also, I would suggest somewhat randomizing the time that you sleep so that multiple users that get the error don't all sleep for exactly the same period of time before retrying. Move your connection allocation into this method as well, so that you hold the connection for the shortest possible period of time.

The comments thus far are also useful. I won't repeat that advice here.

Comment: thank you this is a great start and every ones advice has been more than helpful ill try this out, i appreciate helping out a noob.